# simple HTML DOM parser return wrong elements tree

Tags: php, html, simple-html-dom

I am having problem with HTML DOM parser. This is what I used:

```
$url = 'http://topmmanews.com/2013/04/06/ufc-on-fuel-tv-9-results/';

$page = file_get_html($url);

$ret = $page->find("div.posttext",0);
```

Which is supposed to return me count($ret->children()) = 10. However, it only return me with 3, all the elements after the 3rd

are combined into it and created one element only.

Can anyone help let me know if there is something wrong with my code or it was simple HTML DOM parser bug?

Comment: As far as I can see there are only 4 `div.posttext` element in that html page

Comment: That page [doesn't close several `<div>` tags](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Ftopmmanews.com%2F2013%2F04%2F06%2Fufc-on-fuel-tv-9-results%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0). Parsing invalid HTML can always lead to unpredicted results.

Answer (score 1):

As `Álvaro G. Vicario` pointed out, your target HTML is somehow malformed. I tried your code but as you can see here it shows three children and 6 other nodes:

[image]

But the other way, which might be useful, is to use [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) and [`DOMXPath`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) like this:

```
$url = 'http://topmmanews.com/2013/04/06/ufc-on-fuel-tv-9-results/';
$html = file_get_contents($url);
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$dom_xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

// XPATH to return the first DIV with class "posttext"
$elements = $dom_xpath->query("(//div[@class='posttext'])[1]");
```

Then you can iterate through child nodes and read the values or whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

phpquery uses DOM so it's a more reliable parser with bad html:

```
$html = file_get_contents('http://topmmanews.com/2013/04/06/ufc-on-fuel-tv-9-results/');
$dom = phpQuery::newDocumentHTML($html);
$ret = $dom->find("div.posttext")->eq(0);
echo count($ret->children());
#=> 10
```